# AJAX request and append to list after press enter

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send and Input Text value to a PHP PAGE via ajax when user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The idea is:

- User write a code on a INPUT TEXT
- User press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- AJAX calls ACTION.PHP and passes the value of the INPUT TEXT
- ACTION.PHP returns and HTML content (via database)
- HTML Content is added on the page who called ACTION.PHP via ajax.

Other issue is that I would like to add 1 or more items on the list and not OVERWRITE it...

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".code").bind("enterKey",function(e){                

      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "ACTION.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
});

</script>

<input name="code" class="code" type="text" name="code" />

<div id="responsecontainer"></div>
```

AND MY ACTION PHP is like this:

```
<?php
/* connection to database code is here.. just remove because isn't necessary */

/* Query code is here too */

echo $line['nome'];

?>
```

As you can see, the `$(".code").bind("enterKey",function(e){` ISN'T working and I don't know how to change DIV #responsecontainer to a LIST `<ul><li></li></ul>` and add new `<li>` to each request.

Comment: There is no `enterKey` event. Use the `keyup` event, and test the key code to see if it's the `Return` key.

Comment: You're missing the `data:` option to `$.ajax()` to pass the value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `keydown` event, and test the keyCode to see if it's the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Then you need to pass `this.value` to the PHP script using the `data:` option.

```
$(function() {
    $(".code").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ACTION.php",
                data: { code: this.value },
                dataType: "HTML",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#responsecontainer ul").append($("<li>", { html: response }));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You shold change your HTML to:

```
<div id="responsecontainer">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

Then the AJAX code above will be able to append `<li>` elements to this list.